# use regex to match a URL to a pattern, returning an array of keys

Tags: php, regex

I'm putting together a router in PHP that matches a pattern, like "users/:id", to a route, like "users/123", returning something like "id" => 123. This is what I have so far.

```
function match_path($path, $pattern){
if ($path == $pattern){
  return true;
}
// check for :replacements
if (strpos($pattern, ":")!== false) {
  // split path & pattern into fragments
  $split_path =  explode('/',$path);
  $split_pattern = explode('/', $pattern);
  // check that they are the same length
  if (count($split_path) !== count($split_pattern)){
    return false;
  }
  // iterate over pattern
  foreach ($split_pattern as $index => $fragment) {
    // if fragment is wild
    if (strpos($fragment, ":") == 0){
      $params[substr($fragment, 1)] = $split_path[$index];
    // if fragment doesn't match
    } elseif ($fragment !== $split_path[$index]) {
      return false;
    }
    // continue if pattern matches
  }
  // returns hash of extracted parameters
  return $params;
}
return false;

}
```

I'm certain there must be a way to do this cleanly with a regular expression.

Better yet, there may well be a PHP function that does this.

Comment: I am unsure what you are planning to do with it, but `.htaccess` might even be possible, which is usually used for fancy url's

Comment: It seems like he is trying to implement routing at the application level. `.htaccess` is faster but less flexible from a development standpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP on Rails, eh? ;-)

**Important note about the behavior of `strpos`:** you should check using the **strict** `===` operator, because it may return false (source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php
). After a cursory read/test this is all I see wrong with the script...

```
<?php
// routes-test.php

echo "should be [ id => 123 ]:\n";
var_dump( match_path( 'user/123', 'user/:id' ) );

function match_path($path, $pattern) { ... }
?>

// cmd line
$ php routes-test.php # your implementation
should be [ id => 123 ]:
array(2) {
  ["ser"]=>
  string(4) "user"
  ["id"]=>
  string(3) "123"
}
$ php routes-test.php # using ===
should be [ id => 123 ]:
array(1) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(3) "123"
}
```

You should take a YAGNI approach to using regex. If all you'd be doing is matching stuff like `/^:\w+$/`, then you can do it faster and in a comparable number of lines with strpos and friends.

Answer (score 1):

How about using something like this?

```
/**
 * Compares a url to a pattern, and populates any embedded variables
 * Returns false if the pattern does not match
 * Returns an array containing the placeholder values if the pattern matches
 * If the pattern matches but does not contain placeholders, returns an empty array
 */
function checkUrlAgainstPattern($url, $pattern) {
    // parse $pattern into a regex, and build a list of variable names
    $vars = array();
    $regex = preg_replace_callback(
        '#/:([a-z]+)(?=/|$)#',
        function($x) use (&$vars) {
            $vars[] = $x[1];
            return '/([^/]+)';
        },
        $pattern
    );

    // check $url against the regex, and populate variables if it matches
    $vals = array();
    if (preg_match("#^{$regex}$#", $url, $x)) {
        foreach ($vars as $id => $var) {
            $vals[$var] = $x[$id + 1];
        }
        return $vals;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This uses [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) to both convert the pattern to a regular expression and capture the list of placeholders, and then [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to evaluate the url against the resulting regex and pull out the placeholder values.

Some examples of usage:

```
checkUrlAgainstPattern('/users/123', '/users/:id');
// returns array('id' => '123')

checkUrlAgainstPattern('/users/123/123', '/users/:id');
// returns false

checkUrlAgainstPattern('/users/123/details', '/users/:id/:page');
// returns array('id' => '123', 'page' => 'details')
```